# Telegram Bot Getting User Phone Number

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

I have an issue with my bot:

I want to authorize user via phone_request. But it crashes. Although I get user phone. By phone_request I mean that I'm asking user for a phone number with this:

```
def get_keyboard():
    contact_button = KeyboardButton('Start conversation', 
    request_contact=True)
    reply_keyboard = [[contact_button]]
    return reply_keyboard
```

I catch it with this:

```
dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.contact, 
contact_callback,pass_user_data=True))
```

Than it goes there:

```
def contact_callback(bot, update):
  contact = update.effective_message.contact
  phone = contact.phone_number
  print(contact)
  print(phone)
  update.message.reply_text('Thanks your data is accepted', get_authorized(), resize_keyboard=True)
```

`get_authorized` is simply this:

```
def get_authorized():
    reply_keyboard = [['Pay', 'Why I'm in debt'], ['Remind Later']]
    return reply_keyboard
```

What can go wrong here?

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/telegram/ext/dispatcher.py", line 279, in process_update
    handler.handle_update(update, self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/telegram/ext/messagehandler.py", line 169, in handle_update
    return self.callback(dispatcher.bot, update, **optional_args)
  File "/home/ubuntu/Telegram_bot_OSDI/Telegram_Bot_OSDI_22.py", line 164, in contact_callback
    update.message.reply_text('Спасибо! Ваши данные приняты', get_authorized(), resize_keyboard=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/telegram/message.py", line 455, in reply_text
    return self.bot.send_message(self.chat_id, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/telegram/bot.py", line 65, in decorator
    result = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/telegram/bot.py", line 90, in decorator
    result = self._request.post(url, data, timeout=kwargs.get('timeout'))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/telegram/utils/request.py", line 309, in post
    headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/telegram/utils/request.py", line 223, in _request_wrapper
    raise BadRequest(message)
telegram.error.BadRequest: Unsupported parse_mode
```

Comment: Change `'Why I'm in debt'` to `"Why I'm in debt"` first of all

Comment: @martineau, I've edited the post in response to your question.

Comment: Sergey: That's helps a little bit, but where/how are you calling `get_keyboard()`? You need to [edit] your question and provide a MCVE (or something much closer to one). See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).